# What is the safest way to create the coredata stack

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4, swift5

In order to initiate the coredata stack in app delegate is not recommended as it will create issue in a multi threaded environment. Therefore, I created a separate class for coredata stack and then a separate class to handle operations. And in the Coredata stack class it crashes. What am I missing here ?

CoreData Stack Class

[image]

Code looks like this

```
class CoreDataManager {

 static let sharedManager = CoreDataManager()

 private init() {} //Singleton

 lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

  let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyDatabase")

  container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (_, error) in

    if let error = error as NSError? {
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
  })
   return container
 }()

lazy var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
       return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
}()

lazy var cacheContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
       return self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
}()

lazy var updateContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
       let _updateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
       _updateContext.parent = self.viewContext
       return _updateContext
}()


}
```

This is how I access it

```
class StorageManager: NSObject {

 lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {

      return CoreDataManager.sharedManager.persistentContainer.viewContext
}()
lazy var privateMOC: NSManagedObjectContext = {

      return CoreDataManager.sharedManager.updateContext
}()



 private func synchronize(privateMOC: NSManagedObjectContext) {

    do {
        try privateMOC.save() 

        self.managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
            do {
               
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
               // "Saved to main context"
            } catch {
                print("Could not synchonize data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not synchonize data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}


}
```

A sample operation would look like this

```
func deleteContact(contactID: String) {
     let privateMOC = self.privateMOC
     privateMOC.performAndWait {

        let request: NSFetchRequest<Contact> = Contact.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "contact_id= %@", contactID)
        let result = try? privateMOC.fetch(request)

            for object in result! {
                privateMOC.delete(object)
            }

        self.synchronize(privateMOC: privateMOC)

    }
}
```

Comment: Add code, error messages etc as text and not as images. I prefer to set up the persistent container and store inside the init method but I am not sure if this is related to your crash

Comment: there is no error displayed in the console other than hitting the line where it crashes

Comment: Why do you need all those lazy variables? Is your app only using Core Data at some occasions? Remove lazy at least in CoreDataManager and move the set up into the init as I mentioned earlier and see if that works.

Comment: There is a data sync happening in the app which takes about 5 minutes thats why lazy variables are declared. If i write it in init how can i access the persistant container ?

Comment: You still have it as a property in your class

Comment: init (persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer) { self.persistentContainer = persistentContainer }.  ???

Comment: I can recommend this blog post from Marcus Zarra [My Core Data Stack](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/). Marcus has written a few books on CoreData so does know his stuff.